# May a binary executable vary with the threads used for the compiler (gcc)?

Tags: multithreading, gcc, makefile, compiler-optimization

I recently had a bug in a gentoo linux package: The code did not compile properly if it was compiled in several threads. Often people report [problems with compilation in parallel make jobs](https://bugs.gentoo.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=makeopts&list_id=2147550) in gentoo, where all programs were build from source.

This lead me to the question, if it is true in general, that the compiler should create the same binaries when compiling with a different number of threads? (like `MAKEOPTS="-j1"` or `MAKEOPTS="-j9"`)

If the binaries may differ, will the optimization effort (`-O2`) be the same?

Comment: `-j` is a Make thing (see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html)), not a compiler thing.  Make just fires multiple compiler processes in parallel, each compiling a different source file.  If you didn't get the correct result, your makefile is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Compilers are not multi-threaded.
2. Compilers are deterministic. The same compiler run on the same source code with the same options should produce identical object code apart from timestamps.

Comment: Or at least that's what we fervently hope they do! There's no fundamental reason for them not to be multi threaded other than no one would want to waste time writing one when external tools like make can do you a parallel build already.

Comment: @bazza That's the way they *are.* (A) single-threaded and (B) deterministic. I speak from compiler construction experience. I don't know what evidential basis, if any, you have for your remark. There have been research efforts into multi-threaded compilers, and tats the way they remain. Research. And a non-deterministic compiler couldn't pass its own QA.

Comment: I know that's the way they are. But for sake of debate a multi threaded compiler wouldn't necessarily be non-deterministic, would it. And given that one can compile separate source code files in parallel with existing tools I'm slightly lost as to why a multi threaded compiler would be of much use. I know I don't write source code files so large that a multi threaded compiler would help me.

Comment: However, compilers aren't necessarily deterministic.  (See e.g. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html regarding `-fno-guess-branch-probability`.)